# Calling a template with template parameters from a std::integer_sequence

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

Scratching my head. Given that I have the following integer sequence:

`std::integer_sequence<int,0,1,2>`

And I have the following template:

`template<int a, int b, int c> void myFunction() {}`

Is there any way to call the template with the integer sequence as template parameters?

`myFunction<std::integer_sequence<int,0,1,2>>();` This does not compile

I found some examples here on stack overflow how to pass the integer sequence as function parameters, but unfortunately this is not an option in my case.
I can't use a parameter pack either as I already use a parameter pack for other things in the same context.

I am using C++17

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: This is pretty unclear " I can't use a parameter pack either as I already use a parameter pack for other things in the same context."  Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might write a helper template, e.g.

```
template<typename T, T... I>
auto helper(std::integer_sequence<T, I...>)
{
    myFunction<I...>();
}
```

Then call it as

```
helper(std::integer_sequence<int,0,1,2>{});
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZAgUA4N8HIO0y0v8)